# Is GWT GSS parser supposed to be sensitive to space between the property and the semicolon in media queries?

Tags: gwt

Using GSS in a UiBinder template (GWT 2.8.1), the following is parsed and works:

```
  @media ( max-width: 767px) {
    ...
  }
```

However, when a space appears between `max-width` and `:` (which in my case is inserted by the IDE's formatter), GSS parsing fails:

```
  @media ( max-width : 767px) {
    ...
  }
```

The resulting GWT compilation error looks like this:

```
binding: formfactor=desktop
binding: user.agent=safari
Compiling module com.example.ExampleDev
   Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.example.client.views.desktop.DesktopShellView.DesktopShellViewUiBinder'
      Rebinding com.example.client.views.desktop.DesktopShellView.DesktopShellViewUiBinder
         Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator
            [ERROR] Unable to parse CSS
com.google.gwt.thirdparty.common.css.compiler.ast.GssParserException: Parse error in uiBinder_com.example.client.views.desktop_DesktopShellView_DesktopShellViewUiBinderImpl_GenCss_style7318912838006262484.gss at line 18 column 22:
  @media ( max-width : 767px) {
                     ^

    at com.google.gwt.thirdparty.common.css.compiler.ast.GssParserCC.parse(GssParserCC.java:227)
    at com.google.gwt.thirdparty.common.css.compiler.ast.GssParserCC.parse(GssParserCC.java:247)
```

Comment: This might be better as a bug report than a "question".